# Angularjs filter cumulative array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue filtering my result sets in an ng-repeat.  The filter gets run on each iteration through the ng-repeat cycle (so if I have 10 dispatches returned by `currentDispatch.dispatches` it will run 10 times).  The first time though, `runs` will only have 1 element.  The next time through it will have 2, then 3, and so forth.  What the results look like on my screen is....

[1],[1],[1,3],[1,3,4]

How can i make it so it only runs the filter once as it has all the elements to filter against?  I need only the final result set, not a result of every iteration through.

my custom filter

```
angular.module('prototype').filter('dispatchedForMyEquipment', ['Config', function(Config){
    return function(runs){
        var result = []
        var myEquipment = Config.getEquipment();
        runs.forEach(function(run, index, array){
            myEquipment.forEach(function(dispatchEquipment, index, array){
                if (run.units.indexOf(dispatchEquipment)!= -1){
                    result.push(run);
                    return
                }
            });         
        })
        return result
    }
}])
```

my ng-repeat clause

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="dispatch in ($state.current.data.latest ?
 (currentDispatch.dispatches | orderBy: '-time' | dispatchedForMyEquipment)
 : (currentDispatch.dispatches | orderBy: '-time'))  track by $index">
```

I will take the track by $index out once I fix the issue at hand.

Answer (score -1):

Ng-repeat does watch for itself , maybe u are getting data through a ajax request.  Having said that just mask your ng-repeat with ng-if with the condition that it has all 10 elements... A dirty way right.

Comment: That's not going to work... that requires me to know how many elements are in my list, which I don't know.

Comment: Misunderstood your question. You want to run the ng-repeat only once, its now about showing the result set once its done.